# setting a border colour on hover to a dynamic colour from the database

Tags: php, jquery, css

OK so I have uls which are categories. Each li within has a border 1px in white, which cannot be seen as the li is on a white background, in order to stop them moving when the li is hovered over.

On hover I want to change the border colour to what's been chosen for that category by the user from the database.

here is the markup

```
<ul class="productRange">

    {foreach $productRange index range}

        <li style="border-top: 1px solid {$range.productsCategoryColour}">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color{$range.productsCategoryColour}">{$range.itemTitle}</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">

             {foreach $range.products ind product}

             <li class="productCategoryNugget">

             <a href="{$product.productURL}">
             <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />{$product.productTitle}
             </a>

            </li>

            {/foreach}

            </ul>

        </li>       

    {/foreach}

</ul>
```

CSS...

```
 .productCategoryNugget:hover {
      border: 1px solid;
  }
```

the category colour is stored in $range.productsCategoryColour which sets the border-top of the containing li fine. It's the li's inside the ul productCategoryView which have a border appear on hover, right now it's black on them all, fine, but I'd like it to match the colour of the category they are in

here is the output HTML

```
     <ul class="productRange">


        <li style="border-top: 1px solid #0d2d94">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color:#0d2d94">CADAC Patio Range</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">


                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="stratos">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Stratos 4 Burner
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="stratos-3-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Stratos 3 Burner
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="braai-maxx">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />BraaiMaxx
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-4-burner-side-table">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Meridian 4 Burner & Side Table
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-3-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Titan 4 Burner
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="free-standing-meridian-4-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Free-Standing Meridian 4 Burner
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Meridian 3 Burner & Side Burner
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="free-standing-meridian-3-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Free-Standing Meridian
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="titan">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Stratos
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-accessories">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Meridian Accessories
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-4-burner-side-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Meridian
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-3-burner-side-table">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Meridian 3 Burner & Side Table
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="meridian-4-burner">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Titan
                        </a>
                    </li>


            </ul>

        </li>       


        <li style="border-top: 1px solid #ff0000">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color:#ff0000">CADAC Charcoal Range</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">


                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="charcoal-mate-50cm">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Charcoal Mate 50cm
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="some-bbq">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Charcoal Pro Deluxe 57cm
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="some-other-bbq">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Charcoal Pro 57cm
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productCategoryNugget">
                        <a href="charcoal-mate-57cm">
                        <img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />Charcoal Mate 57cm
                        </a>
                    </li>


            </ul>

        </li>       


        <li style="border-top: 1px solid #ebe300">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color:#ebe300">CADAC Chef Range</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">



            </ul>

        </li>       


        <li style="border-top: 1px solid #00a2ff">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color:#00a2ff">CADAC Braai Range</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">



            </ul>

        </li>       


        <li style="border-top: 1px solid #0d8a02">
            <span class="productRangeTitle"style="color:#0d8a02">CADAC Accessories</span>

            <ul class="productCategoryView">



            </ul>

        </li>       
    </ul>
```

Rich :)

Comment: Can you post your outputted HTML instead of the PHP?  It will be easy to use jQuery to do what you want, just need to see your HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

As bipen said, adding a data attribute or even a rel attribut would work best. Another way would be iterating through the lis parents:

```
$(function() {
    $('li.productCategoryNugget').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('border-top', $(this).parents('li').css('border-top'));
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('border-top', 'solid 1px white');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many other ways to get this...traversing the DOM.. finding `parent()` of hover element and gettin the color.. but the easiet and better performancewise(to my knowledge ) is by adding HTML 5 data attribute to li..

```
<li class="productCategoryNugget" data-color="{$range.productsCategoryColour}" >
```

and with jquery

```
$('.productCategoryNugget').hover(function(){
    var proColor=$(this).data('color'); //get data color value
    $(this).css('border-top','1px solid '+proColor) ;
},function(){
     $(this).css('border-top','1px solid')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the color from the span holding it. Something like

```
$(".productCategoryNugget").hover(
    function(){
             var parentLi = $(this).parent().parent();
             $(this).css("border-top": parentLi.css("border-top") );
     },
    //unset the border-color
    function(){
        $(this).css("border-top": "1px solid" );
  });
```

Comment: @Alex my bad, should be `css`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think it should be. Take `color` of `$(this).parent().parent().children('.productRangeTitle')` and then use as you want.

Here is a fiddle example. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTqwH/)

Answer (score 0):

well it turns out, I was over complicating the situation. I gave the styles to the , set the border-color in the inline style, then for the li a have a margin of 1px and a border of 0px, then on hover, set the border to 1px and margin to 0px, all in CSS, no jQuery needed...

CSS ....

```
.productCategoryNugget a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
color: #55687A;
margin: 1px;
}

.productCategoryNugget a:hover {
border: 1px solid;
margin: 0;
}
```

Markup (note I'm using DWOO template engine)

```
{foreach $range.products ind product}

<li class="productCategoryNugget">
<a href="{$product.productURL}" style="border-color: {$range.productsCategoryColour}">
<img src="/assets/layout/no_image_image.png" />{$product.productTitle}
</a>
</li>
{/foreach}
```